# .NET / EF: How do I get around the 'ambiguity problem' to create a query with a group by?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using the latest version of .NET Core (.NET 5) and Entity Framework Core 6 (preview) to connect to a MySQL database. I am trying to use GroupBy to generate a group by query to execute on the DB server, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation). Unfortunately, this fails to compile with the error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource, TKey>>)' and 'System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable, System.Func<TSource, TKey>)

This error is related to LINQ and EF Core sharing the same methods, and is discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18220). I have tried the suggested workaround of creating extension methods for each LINQ call, with the following code:

```
    {
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> Where<TEntity>(this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TEntity> obj, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
        {
            return System.Linq.Queryable.Where(obj, predicate);
        }

        public static IQueryable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, Expression<Func<TSource, TElement>> elementSelector, Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult>> resultSelector)
        {
            return System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy(source, keySelector, elementSelector, resultSelector);
        }

        public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
        {
            return System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy(source, keySelector);
        }

    }
```

This fixes the issue with 'Where()', however the error remains for GroupBy(). Should I be using a different extension method to resolve this, or some other workaround? I cant use AsEnumerable() as this retrieves all records before performing the grouping.

Comment: Sorry, I was running EF core version 6.0.0-preview.2.21154.2 in an attempt to get around this issue, but I mis-tagged this question as standard EF 6.

Comment: Added a corresponding (new) tag for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.AsQueryable()` on your `DbSet<T>` when `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is not needed and visa versa to remove ambiguity:

```
dbContext.YourEntities
    .AsQueryable() // or .AsAsyncEnumerable()
    // ...
    .GroupBy(ye => ye.PropertyA);
```

[Note this will not be an issue in EFCore 6](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24041)

Comment: Thanks, .AsQueryable() and .AsAsyncEnumerable() resolved the issue. Although I tried running the preview version of EF Core 6 having read that, it and it still exists unfortunately. Hopefully it will be resolved by the time of the full release.